# Improving the visual quality of Theora when using Xuggler

Tags: java, ffmpeg, codec, ogg-theora, xuggle

I'm looking for fellow users, who are using Xuggler to produce video encoded with Theora. I've tried a lot of different options to get "good" quality using presets to no avail. I would love to get quality anywhere close to what I can produce with the Miro converter tools defaults. Sadly, the web doesn't seem to have much to say except that we should all "use ffmpeg2theora" which is not an option when using Xuggler, and I have to use Xuggler in this case. 

My listener which configures the codecs is here: http://pastebin.com/MX2r5KsC

And my reference preset file is here: http://pastebin.com/fBeZxSGr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution was found by a colleague / client on a related project. The resolution is surprisingly simple, and consists of the following three lines of code:

`coder.setFlag(IStreamCoder.Flags.FLAG_QSCALE, false);
coder.setBitRate(200000);
coder.setTimeBase(IRational.make(1,25));`

This forces Xuggler to encode using a constant bitrate of 200kbps and with a frame rate of 25 fps. I hope this helps my fellow Xuggle users out there.